# How to disable onItemSelectedListener to be invoked when setting selected item by code

Tags: android, listener, spinner

Just wondering how you handle the following problem: a result is calculated depending on two spinners' selected items. To handle the UI things, i.e. a user picks a new item in one of the spinners, I install a listener using `setOnItemSelectedListener` for the spinner in my `onCreate()` method of the activity.

Now: that works, of course, fine. The listener's work is to trigger a new calculation of the result.

The problem: because I intercept `onPause()` `onResume()` to save/restore the last state, I got a method that **sets** these two spinners' selected item programmatically like in here:

```
startSpinner.setSelection(pStart);
destSpinner.setSelection(pDest);
```

These two calls invoke the listeners, too! My calculation method for the result plus the notification of a new result set is invoked twice here!

A stupid direct approach for this would be to have a boolean variable **disabling** whatever the listener does inside, setting it before setting the selected items and resetting it afterwards.
Okay. But is there a better method??

I don't want listeners to be called by code - actions, only by user actions! :-(

How do you do it?
Thanks!

Comment: You can use setSelection(pStart, false) for animate param. But it's not working all the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have an easier, and I think, better solution. Since I had to refresh the spinners even after initialization, this is a more generic approach.
Please refer the accepted answer:

[Undesired onItemSelected calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21747917/undesired-onitemselected-calls/21751327#21751327)

Comment: Thanks very much, sounds like a great approach! I will have to change my code when I get time...

Comment: Funny that you also answered your own question - just like I did before in my question.. :)

Comment: :D yeah. What's even funnier is that I understood the working of the callback after seeing your answer :)

Answer (score 54):

A cleaner solution, in my opinion, to differentiate between programmatic and user-initiated changes is the following:

Create your listener for the spinner as both an OnTouchListener and OnItemSelectedListener

```
public class SpinnerInteractionListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, View.OnTouchListener {

    boolean userSelect = false;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        userSelect = true;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        if (userSelect) { 
            // Your selection handling code here
            userSelect = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Add the listener to the spinner registering for both event types

```
SpinnerInteractionListener listener = new SpinnerInteractionListener();
mSpinnerView.setOnTouchListener(listener);
mSpinnerView.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);
```

This way, any unexpected calls to your handler method due to initialization or re-initialization will be ignored.

Comment: Definitely the best solution I have seen to this.  Sometimes I wish Spinner were deprecated!

Comment: If make SpinnerInteractionListener abstract class and create abstract method onSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id, boolean userSelected) then you can catch all of the events (user, init, etc) and react to them in different ways. That's what I needed. The perfect solution, thanks.

Comment: I have tried everything I possibly could to fix my problem related to the Spinner, and this is what finally did it. I believe that anyone who ever implements a Spinner should do it this way. The API is basically broken out of the box, this was the missing functionality. Thank you very much!

Comment: it fails if user "touch" view [but dont change data] and later if app set spinner - then listener is executed

Comment: For my use-case, the devices have a hardware keyboard and hypothetically could be selected with, for example, arrow keys rather than touch.

Answer (score 11):

Okay, I got it working the way I want to now.

The thing to understand here (and I did not when I was writing that question...) is that everything in Android runs in one thread - the UI thread.

Meaning: even though you set Spinner's values here and there: they are only updated (visually) **and** their listeners are only called **after** all methods you're currently in (like `onCreate`, `onResume` or whatever) are finished.

This allows the following:

- keep the selected positions in field variables. (like `currentPos1`, `currentPos2`)
- the listeners `onItemSelectedListener()` call a method like `refreshMyResult()` or whatever.
- when setting positions programmatically, set the spinners **and** call your own refresh method manually right after that.

The `refreshMyResult()` method looks like this:

```
int newPos1 = mySpinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();
int newPos2 = mySpinner2.getSelectedItemPosition();
// only do something if update is not done yet
if (newPos1 != currentPos1 || newPos2 != currentPos2) {
    currentPos1 = newPos1;
    currentPos2 = newPos2;

    // do whatever has to be done to update things!

}
```

Because the listeners will be called later - and by then, the remembered position in currentPos is already updated - nothing will happen and no unnecessary update of anything else will take place.
When a user selects a new value in one of the spinners, well - the update will be performed accordingly!

That's it! :-)

Ahh - one more thing: the answer to my question is: No.
The listeners cannot be disabled (easily) and will be called whenever a value is changed.

Comment: I had a similar problem using onCheckChanged, and the way I solved it was by verifying that the code was being called by user input, using buttonView's isPressed method. So with respect, I think your approach may be ill-advised, unless of course I'm misunderstanding the question. Look into verifying that it was called by the user rather than your onPause() and onResume() methods.

Comment: I like Zordid's approach because no matter where the input came from (user input or previously saved), the right thing to do in my app is nothing unless the value changed.

Comment: @Zach: isPressed() is always false inside onItemSelectedListener(). Per the doc, isPressed() Indicates whether the view is CURRENTLY in pressed state. OnItemSelectedListener register a callback to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView HAS BEEN SELECTED. I put a debug message inside onItemSelectedListener() and found isPressed() is always faulse. I dug in the code and found isSelected() might be the correct method to use. but NO, this method is also always falose inside onLitemSelectedListener. So Zordid's method is only solution, and it works as expected in my code.

Answer (score 3):

First add boolean values for stopping spinner listener call

```
  Boolean check = false;
```

Then you add on Touch listener and on Item click Listener Like below code

```
 holder.filters.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
               @Override
               public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                   check = true;
                   return false;
               }
           });

           holder.filters.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
           {

               @Override
               public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position, long id)
               {
                   flag = filterids.get(position);

                   if(check)
                   {
                       check = false;
                       new Applyfilters().execute(flag,"3");
                   }else{

                   }

               }

               @Override
               public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
               {
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               }
           });
```

Its simple working good for stopping server call multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy you can call the `Spinner.setSelection(int position, boolean animate)` method with `false` so the listeners will not react on the change.

Comment: Works fin for me (Api 16)

Comment: The animate argument decides the spinner animation (whether the  selection should be selected directly (false) or not (true)). It has nothing to do with the onItemSelected call.

Comment: This is not the right answer. This doesn't work with me- Android 4.4.4.

Comment: Tried setSelection(spinner, false). No change, triggers the listener. Android 4.4.4

Answer (score 2):

Spinner.setSelection(int position, boolean animate) does trigger the listener on 4.3

Comment: This is not an answer to my question, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I created a library that help for all, that no need to call item onClick action in Spinner
For example:

```
spinner.setSelection(withAction,position);
```

where withAction is a boolean flag, that used for call or not item action

Link on Github:
https://github.com/scijoker/spinner2

Answer (score 2):

My solution is very easy. First initialize a global boolean variable.

```
boolean shouldWork = true;
```

Then use below code in your onCreate() method.

```
Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView adapter, View v, int i, long lng) {
        if (shouldWork) {
               // Do your actions here
        }
        else
            shouldWork = true;
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView)  {

    }
});
```

Now you can use the setSelection method in everwhere without invoking the onItemSelected() method by below code.

```
shouldWork = false;
spinner.setSelection(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `OnItemSelectedListener` for each spinner *after* you have set any previous value in `onResume`.

Comment: The problem is that a running activity might get a new intent that should set the spinners to a new value - thus the activity plus all its listeners is definitely set then!

Also: i tried to deactivate the listener using `setOnItemSelectedListener(null)` before setting the values and restoring the listeners later: without **any** effect! The listeners are called asynchronously! :-(

Answer (score 1):

When Spinner.setSelection(position) is used, it always activates setOnItemSelectedListener()

To avoid firing the code twice I use this solution:

```
private mIsSpinnerFirstCall=true;

...
Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //If a new value is selected (avoid activating on setSelection())
        if(!mIsSpinnerFirstCall) {
            // Your code goes gere
        }
        mIsSpinnerFirstCall = false;
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }
});
```

This solution is valid when you are sure that Spinner.setSelection(position) us used. Also, it is important to set mIsSpinnerFirstCall=true each time before using Spinner.setSelection(position)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, since I'm triggering spinner programmatically, then I just have to add **spinnerSelected** flag after **spinner.performClick()** like below.

```
private var spinnerSelected = false

someView.setOnClickListener {
    spinner.performClick()
    spinnerSelected = true
}

spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
        // do nothing
    }

    override fun onItemSelected(
        parent: AdapterView<*>?,
        view: View?,
        position: Int,
        id: Long
    ) {
        if (spinnerSelected) {
            //... do something

            spinnerSelected = false
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    This following method will help you to stop invoking automatically the selection listener


    yourspinnerobj.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    yourspinnerobj.setOnItemSelectedListener(yourspinnerlistener);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer: `spinner.setClickable(false);` tell spinner that this is not a clickable event before executing the `setSelection` function, and then use `spinner.setClickable(true);` to restore it after the `setSelection` function is executed. after the `setSelection` function is executed. On the other hand, it can also prevent the user from clicking on the spinner during the execution of the `setSelection` function, although the chance of this is too small, but it should be handled in the code.

```java
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
    if(!selectFridaSpinner.isClickable())return;
}
```

```java
spinner.setClickable(false);
spinner.setSelection(2);
spinner.setClickable(true);
```