# Can't find spinner after rotating the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I'm using 'Fragment' to obtain a layout with two 'fragments' so my class extends 'Fragment'.

I'm loading a 'ListView' on the left 'fragment' and on the right 'fragment' I have another modified 'ListView'. Here, I have a 'Spinner' that I have to change it's color.

I have this code:

```
private void loadSpinner(int value) {
    //Not relevant code

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String value = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

   ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));

  //Some code
}
```

The code above is working as expected **UNTIL** I rotate the screen of my device. Here, I'm getting a `nullpointerexception` at `((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));`.

If I comment the above line, since I'm saving the state before rotating the screen, after I rotate the screen, my data is restored and all works as expected **EXCEPT** the spinner that is on light color thus being poorly visible.

I understand that I can create my own 'spinner' layout and solve this matter but I would like to know how can I solve this.

Comment: Where do you call `loadSpinner` from?

Comment: @Szymon Hi. At `onCreateView` I'm doing this `spinner = (Spinner) itemDataLayout.findViewById(R.id.availableValues);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);` and the spinner is loaded from , imagine, `functionX`. When I click on a item on the left `listview` the function  `functionX` is called. If I come from a `savedrestoredstate`, `functionX` is called from `onStart()`

Comment: you probably have `onItemSelected` triggered before `loadSpinner` is  called, which sets the adapter. You could verify the order by putting breakpoints in `onItemSelected` and on line `spinner.setAdapter()` and see what is called first after the rotation

Comment: @Favolas if what I wrote in previous comment is the case, you will always have NPE in the `onItemSelected` due to spinner has no children do display yet. So, you will have two options to fix this, but first you need to check if that is the case.

Comment: @kiruwka Nop. `loadSpinner` comes first

Comment: @Favolas did you verify the order with the debugger ? do both calls come on Main thread ?

Comment: Yep. Checked with breakpoits

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44120/discussion-between-kiruwka-and-favolas)

Comment: @Favolas I debugged a bit and found exact cause of the issue. Please, have a look at my answer.

Comment: it give me a null point objection in textview

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After screen rotation, your `Spinner` view has no children views attached yet (you can verify it by calling `parent.getChildCount()`), thus your `parent.getChildAt(0)` returns null, resulting in `NPE`.

#### Explanations

After activity creation, Android displays its content by calling `onMeasure()` followed by `onLayout()` for each view in the layout hierarchy.

`Spinner` will have its children views created, populated with data from adapter, and attached during call to `onLayout()`, as you can [see here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/Spinner.java#138).

So, normally for your Spinner you will have sequence : `onMeasure` -> `onLayout` -> `onItemSelected`
and since `onLayout` is called before `onItemSelected` - everything works fine for you during initial activity startup.

*Now, lets have a look what happens when you rotate the screen:*

Before Activity is destroyed its `onSavedInstanceState` gets called which propagates the call to `Spinner`'s `onSavedInstanceState` that will save current selected position.

After rotation, your activity is re-created and then its `onRestoreInstanceState` is called.

when Activity#`onRestoreInstanceState` is called it will eventually call to Spinner's [onRestoreInstanceState](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/AbsSpinner.java#439), which has the following code :

```
    SavedState ss = (SavedState) state;
    //...some code
    if (ss.selectedId >= 0) {
        mDataChanged = true;
        //...some more code
    }
```

As you can see, it will always set mDataChanged flag if previous state of the spinner was saved with [onSavedInstanceState](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/AbsSpinner.java#426).

Then, [onMeasure()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/AbsSpinner.java#170) is called, which has the following piece of code :

```
    if (mDataChanged) {
        handleDataChanged();
    }
```

Implementation of [handleDataChanged](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/AdapterView.java#AdapterView.handleDataChanged%28%29)() will eventually call [fireOnSelected](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/AdapterView.java#AdapterView.fireOnSelected%28%29)(), triggering Spinner's `onItemSelected`.

Thus `onItemSelected` gets called during `onMeasure`, before `onLayout`.
And as explained above, `Spinner` has no children before its `onLayout` is called.

Hope the problem is clear now.

#### Workaround

To confirm that behaviour and resolve NPE you could simply provide empty implementation for `onSavedInstanceState`/`onRestoreInstanceState` in your activity (without call to super implementation) :

```
@Override 
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) { /* do nothing */ }
```

This would prevent setting `mDataChanged` and `onMeasure` will not trigger `fireOnSelected`.

#### Extra note

Not calling Activity `super.` implementation when overriding `onSavedInstanceState`/`onRestoreInstanceState` is definitely not recommended, as a minimum you will not be able to automatically save states of your internal views (including your spinner).
I encourage you to only do that to verify the behavior explained above and to see that `NPE` is gone.

The preferable solution is to define `TextView` with desired color for you spinner item in a .xml layout and use it for constructing `ArrayAdapter` for the spinner.

Comment: Many thanks for this explanation. You are right. Gonna implement my custom spinner.

Comment: @Favolas Glad it helped. Please consider accepting. And happy new year!

Comment: Hey..i am having this same issue..i implemented my custom spinner..still getting the same `nullpointerexception`.Did you solve this problem using a custom spinner or something else?

Comment: I solved it [using this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397933/android-spinner-avoid-onitemselected-calls-during-initialization?rq=1)

Comment: @Favolas, did your solution define the color in XML? I have a similar question, but I cannot rely on defining the color in XML because the color is known only at runtime. My question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747884/android-nullpointerexception-spinner-onitemselected-view-parameter-is-null-a

Comment: @kiruwka Your workaround worked for me, thank you very much! But my text color is only known at runtime. Do you know any other solution?  For more info, please see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747884/android-nullpointerexception-spinner-onitemselected-view-parameter-is-null-a