# AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener is returning NULL view

Tags: android, onitemselectedlistener

I have the following code :

```
public class OnboardingActivity extends BaseLoggedInActivity
    implements CountryPickerDialog.ICountryPickerDialogUsers, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
private Spinner _countryCodeSpinner;

.
.
.
    private void setupCountrySpinner() {
        List<String> sortedCountryCodeList = CountryData.getInstance().getSortedCountryCodes();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            R.layout.country_code_spinner_item,
            sortedCountryCodeList);
    _countryCodeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    _countryCodeSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    _countryCodeSpinner
            .setOnTouchListener(getCountryCodeSpinnerTouchListener(_countryCodeSpinner));
    int position = getDefaultCountryNamePosition();
    if (position >= 0) {
        _countryCodeSpinner.setSelection(position);
    }
}

.
.
.
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    _logger.debug("Inside onItemSelected");
    view.setSelected(true);
}
```

I am getting a null pointer exception in the above function **onItemSelected** . Its returning NULL view. This trace i am receiving from one of the user but i am unable to reproduce it myself. What could be reason that onItemSelected is being called with a NULL view ?

Thanks

Comment: it is becuase `_countryCodeSpinner.setSelection(position);` ... the listpopupwindow is not visible so there is no view ... could you provide the version of android on this device? (maybe before API 11 spinner listpopupwindow was more like a dialog)

Comment: The android system version is 4.0.4

Comment: I have the same problem when get fragment from back stack. I will working on it.

Comment: same problem in  API24 (Android7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be caused after the configuration change, e.g rotating the device. Your spinner is recreated and you are receiving a null parameter in the onItemSelected callback.

You can annotate the view in your implementation to be @nullable and then

```
if (view != null) {view.setSelected(true);}
```

If you are using Kotlin try this:

```
override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long){
    view?.isSelected = true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

pretty late Answer I still don't know how it's happennig but you need to change `view :View` in

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    _logger.debug("Inside onItemSelected");
    view.setSelected(true);
}
```

with `view:View?` it can be null when the view isn't avalable

Answer (score 0):

You can block default selection which possible null view by rotation, then perform `setSelection()` explicitly:

```
int position = getDefaultCountryNamePosition();
if (position < 0) {
    position = 0;
}
// Block default selection to custom onItemSelected() from listener initialization
//, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37561529/1074998
// + 1 as fake value because onItemSelected() only triggered by setSelection() if different value. 
_countryCodeSpinner.setSelection(position + 1, false); 
_countryCodeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

// position(without + 1) is our real target.
// set selection explicitly should not null now
_countryCodeSpinner.setSelection(position, false);
```

Note that simply catch null will causes issue if you change UI inside onItemSelected() because layout already refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `spinner.setAdapter(adapter);` with delay after view created.

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76084674/1767847)