# android Spinner: in onItemSelected view is null

Tags: android, spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I have a `Spinner`in my Activity and I define an `OnItemSelectedListener` in `OnResume`:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                                   int pos, long id) {
            final String newLanguage = iconAdapter.getItem(pos).name();
            Helper.getSettings(view.getContext()).setLocale(newLanguage);
            setLocale(new Locale(newLanguage));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Now, `onItemSelected` gets called **twice** during the creation of the activity - without the user selecting anything. The first time everything works as intended, but the second time `view` is `null` and a `NullPointerException` is thrown.

1. Why is `onItemSelected` called at all, when no user selected an item?
2. Why twice?
3. Why is the view the second time `null`?

**Edit:**

So this code happens BEFORE `setOnItemSelectedListener`:

```
spinner = findViewById(R.id.language_spinner);
    LanguageSpinnerAdapter iconAdapter = new LanguageSpinnerAdapter(this, Arrays.asList(LanguageIconEnum.values()));
    spinner.setAdapter(iconAdapter);
    String language = Helper.getSettings(this).getLocale();

    if(language == null){
        spinner.setSelection(0);
    } else {
        switch (language) {
            case "de":
                spinner.setSelection(1);
                break;
            case "fr":
                spinner.setSelection(2);
                break;
            default:
                spinner.setSelection(0);
        }
    }
```

"Am I right to assume, the two times the `OnItemSelected` is called, is when I set the adapter and then when I call `.setSelection()` manually?" - That's not the case, if I delete the manual `setSelection()` part, it's still called twice.

The function `setLocale()` calls `recreate` which populates the `spinner` again, so that's where the second call to `OnItemSelected`comes from.

So what's left:

1. Why is the second call `view` = `null`?
2. What to do against that infinity loop?

Comment: I can't see the rest of your code, but its called at least once when you set some data on the spinner, as an item is "selected" when the data is first put in. Show the code of how you populate your spinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here the answers:

1) Why is `onItemSelected` called at all, when no user selected an item?

- as @Blundell mentioned, when the spinner is populated, an item is selected and therefore `OnItemSelected` is called.

2) Why twice?

- In `OnItemSelected` (in `setLocale`) I call recreate, which populates the spinner a second time.

3) Why is the view the second time null?

- **???**
  I'd really loved an answer to that question.

Solution was:

```
if(lastPos != -1 && lastPos != pos){
   final String newLanguage = iconAdapter.getItem(pos).name();
   Helper.getSettings(view.getContext()).setLocale(newLanguage);
   setLocale(new Locale(newLanguage));
}
lastPos = pos;
```

Anybody knows the answer to question 3?

Comment: Could you please post the error log to check where the `NullPointerException` is being thrown at?

Comment: `Helper.getSettings(view.getContext()).setLocale(newLanguage);` `view` is `null` @ `view.getContext()`

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `spinner.setAdapter(adapter);` with delay after view created.

```
void initAdapter() {
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>( ... );
   spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
   spinner.setSelection(0);
}


void onCreate(...) or onViewCreated( ... ) {
   * * *

    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> initAdapter(), 200);
}
```