# Android: How to deny to execute onItemSelected after on create in onCreateOptionMenu?

Tags: android, spinner

I have the following code for spinner on the actionBar:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.transaction_filter_menu, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.spinner);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.actions, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Logger.d("onItemSelected "+position);
            //mTranactionsController.filterData();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Problem is that event onItemSelected is executed after onCreate when no item is selected. First item is selected by default.

How can i deny to this behaviour please?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397933/android-spinner-avoid-onitemselected-calls-during-initialization)

put `spinner.setSelection(0,false)` before `setAdapter()`

Comment: Still is calling onItemSelected in default

Answer (score 0):

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one) will help you out. You can then also add a description like "Select one"