# Spinner Working by using OnItemSelectedListner

Tags: android

I am trying to connect different pages by using spinner.But in my code while running, the second page i.e the page after clicking the item on spinner is shown first then the main page on which the spinner is there shown.So, Can anyone help in knowing the error?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
Spinner sp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    String [] list={"A","B","C"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,list);
    sp.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
          "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(),
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  switch (position){
         case 0:{
           Intent in= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),A.class);
         startActivity(in);
           break;
      }
  }
}}
```

**XML File:**

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `onItemSelected` is triggered automatically first time you open your activity

Comment: So what should be done to remove the trigger?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397933/android-spinner-avoid-onitemselected-calls-during-initialization

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Spinner : Avoid onItemSelected calls during initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397933/android-spinner-avoid-onitemselected-calls-during-initialization)