# Spinner calling same function multiple times while opening Activity in android

Tags: android

```
ArrayAdapter<String> deptAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(Courses.this, R.layout.profile_spinner_textview, coursetype);

                spinner1.setAdapter(deptAdapter);
                Log.d("co_id", String.valueOf(coursetypeid));

ArrayAdapter<String> centAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(Courses.this, R.layout.profile_spinner_textview, centertype);
                spinner2.setAdapter(centAdapter);

     spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    co_id=coursetypeid.get(i);
                    Log.d("co_id",co_id);


                    loaddata();



                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });
            spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    cent_id=centerid.get(i);
                     loaddata();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });
```

while opening activity same function calling multiple times. how to avoid this. i want call same function while selecting items from spinners. please help me

Comment: It's because when your activity open _setOnItemSelectedListener_ will be triggered initially.

Comment: what i have to do

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397933/android-spinner-avoid-onitemselected-calls-during-initialization)

Comment: you saved my life bro. thank you