# Neutral state of Spinner and Toggle Button

Tags: kotlin

This is my dilema:
I have an activity that uses a toggle button(A00) with the code below. When the activity is created, the function sendCommand is not called(I have to check and uncheck to the uncheck command happen). It's like the toggle button has a neutral state when is created.

```
A00.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
    if (isChecked) {
        sendCommand("1050000")
        A00.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(248, 250, 237))
        A00.setTextColor(Color.rgb(96, 96, 96))
    } else {
        sendCommand("0050000")
        A00.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(96, 96, 96))
        A00.setTextColor(Color.rgb(248, 250, 237)) }
}
```

Then I have this other activity that uses a spinner. As soon the activity is created, the spinner starts at position 0, which runs the function sendCommand without doing anything.

I need the spinner to behave like the toggle button, with something like a "neutral state"
The sendCommand cannot run when the activity is created.
Thanks!

```
SC19.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}
    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {

        val selectedItem = view as TextView
        if (position == 0) { sendCommand("0000219") }
        if (position == 1) { sendCommand("1000219")
            selectedItem.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#f8faed"))
            selectedItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff4500"))
        }
        if (position == 2) { sendCommand("1060219")
            selectedItem.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#454545"))
            selectedItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#32cd32"))
        }
        if (position == 3) { sendCommand("1100219")
            selectedItem.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#f8faed"))
            selectedItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1e90ff"))
        }
        if (position == 4) { sendCommand("1040219")
            selectedItem.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#454545"))
            selectedItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffff00"))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In other words, I want this block of code to run only the second time it's called. Like a post increment. Is there a way to do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It does not have a neutral state, but rather a default state. Effectively creating the toggle button does not trigger the check change listener, as the state is not changed, but set.

The most off-the-bat solution would be to extract the code of

```
   sendCommand("1050000")
   A00.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(248, 250, 237))
   A00.setTextColor(Color.rgb(96, 96, 96))
```

To a separate function and also call it in an activity/fragment callback.

The second part of the question is a repost, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397933/android-spinner-avoid-onitemselected-calls-during-initialization).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you give me a brief example on that? "separate function and also call it in an activity/fragment creation". Thanks!

Comment: Sure!
Make a separate like this, in the same file:

`fun setCheckedState(){
        sendCommand("1050000")
        A00.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(248, 250, 237))
        A00.setTextColor(Color.rgb(96, 96, 96))
}`

Then, call it like this:

`override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setCheckedState()
    }`

And in your initial function:

`A00.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
    if (isChecked) {
        setCheckedState()
          } else {
        ...}`