# Spinner onItemSelected nedded only once, Android Studio

Tags: android

I am trying to implement language change using an `spinner` located in the `toolbar`. Right now I have the following code for the `spinner`:

```
initList();
Spinner spinnerCountries = findViewById(R.id.spinner_limba);
mAdapter = new SpinnerAdapterTara(Harta.this, mCountryList);
    spinnerCountries.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    spinnerCountries.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TaraITEM clickedItem = (TaraITEM) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        String clickedCountryName = clickedItem.getCountryName();
        if (clickedCountryName.equals("FR")){
            setLocale("fr");
            recreate();
        } else if (clickedCountryName.equals("EN")){
            setLocale("en");
            recreate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```

The `initList();` creates the list of languages. The problem right here it's about the `onItemSelected` , because if I choose `fr` or `en`, the  `setLocale("fr")/setLocale("en"); recreate();` will run continously, freezing my app. I need a solution to implement the `onItemSelected` only once, like a `onChangeListener` or something. The app should change it's language when the `spinner` value is changed.

EDIT: I added the `setLocale()`:

```
private void setLocale(String limba){
    Locale locale = new Locale(limba);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale= locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Setare limba", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("Limba mea", limba);
    editor.apply();
}
```

EDIT: added `initList()`

```
private void initList() {
    mCountryList = new ArrayList<>();
    mCountryList.add(new TaraITEM("RO", R.drawable.steag_ro));
    mCountryList.add(new TaraITEM("EN", R.drawable.steag_en));
    mCountryList.add(new TaraITEM("FR", R.drawable.steag_fr));
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Spinner : Avoid onItemSelected calls during initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397933/android-spinner-avoid-onitemselected-calls-during-initialization)

Comment: You can check out this answer. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13398044/4957929

Comment: That answer/question is not helping my situation

Comment: When the user can reset the locale after setting it once?

Comment: Can you add your `initList()` implementation?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I edited the question to add that method

Comment: @Pronoy999 The user is supposed to be able to change the language everytime he switches the `spinner's` value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `static` variable to hold the last `selection` and check that before recreating the `activity` which give you flavor like `onChangeListener`

```
//Place inside Harta like global variable
static String lastCountryName = "";

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    TaraITEM clickedItem = (TaraITEM) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String clickedCountryName = clickedItem.getCountryName();

    // compare here before recreating
    if(!clickedCountryName.equals(lastCountryName)) {
        lastCountryName = clickedCountryName;

        if (clickedCountryName.equals("FR")){
            setLocale("fr");
            recreate();
        } else if (clickedCountryName.equals("EN")){
            setLocale("en");
            recreate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Now i need to find why it doesn't switch to `EN`, only to `FR`