# App crashes when clicking on list item: FATAL EXCEPTION: main, .onItemClick

Tags: android, android-studio, arraylist, crash, onitemclick

This code was working fine in eclipse, but now i imported to android studio 4.1.1.I have all latest updates and correct libraries, tried to invalidate caches and restart, clean, tried different deveices and tried different API levels.My app starts well, but when i click on any list item it crashes.154th line is array sort.

```
@SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
public class CribActivity extends Activity
{
private ListView lv1;
private EditText et;
private final String[] lv_arr ={
        "item 1",
        "items amid 1 - 66 here is a lot",
        "Item 66th"
};
private final ArrayList<String> array_sort= new ArrayList<>();
int textlength=0;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    lv1 = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    et = findViewById(R.id.EditText01);

    lv1 = findViewById(R.id.listView);

    lv1.setAdapter(
            new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lv_arr));
    lv1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,
                                      int start, int count, int after)
        {
            // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,
                                  int start, int before, int count)
        {
            textlength = et.getText().length();
            array_sort.clear();
            for (String value : lv_arr) {
                if (textlength <= value.length()) {
                    if (et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(
                            (String)
                                    value.subSequence(0,
                                            textlength))) {
                        array_sort.add(value);
                    }
                }
            }
            lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>
                    (CribActivity.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_sort));
        }
    });


    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String name;
            name = array_sort.get(position);
            for (int i = 0; i < lv_arr.length; i++) {

                if (lv_arr[i]
                        .equalsIgnoreCase(
                                name)) {
                    position = i;

                    break;
                }

            }



            String itemname = Integer.toString(position);

            Intent intent = new Intent();

            intent.setClass(CribActivity.this, ViewActivity.class);

            Bundle b = new Bundle();


            b.putString("defStrID", itemname);

            intent.putExtras(b);


            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

logcat:

```
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: INVALID_SENDER
```

errors in run:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ru.tablica.sputnikovyh, PID: 13145
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
    at ru.tablica.sputnikovyh.CribActivity$2.onItemClick(CribActivity.java:154)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:318)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1159)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3136)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:4064)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3822)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12513)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3024)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2705)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:440)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3400)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:398)
    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12752)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5106)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4909)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4642)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7092)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7061)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7022)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7195)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: `lv_arr` has no items so it can't return a value.. please provide how you initialize `lv_arr`

Comment: `private final String[] lv_arr ={...list items};                                                               
private final ArrayList<String> array_sort= new ArrayList<>();
 int textlength=0;`

Comment: Have you populated these lists with data?

Comment: `@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);


  lv1 = findViewById(R.id.listView);
  et = findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
  
  lv1 = findViewById(R.id.listView);
  
  lv1.setAdapter(
    new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lv_arr));
  lv1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);`

Comment: yes its data inside the array

Answer (score 1):

android `spinners` has an issue that `onItemClick` gets [called unintentionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397933/android-spinner-avoid-onitemselected-calls-during-initialization) with the first item (index of 0) when you launch your activity that holds this spinner. I suspect that this gets called before the data is loaded into lists causing this exception.

Try to check if lists are loaded before you get data as below

```
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String name;

            if (array_sort.size() <= 0) return; // <<<<<<< change here
            if (lv_arr.length <=0) return; // <<<<<<< change here

            name = array_sort.get(position);
            for (int i = 0; i < lv_arr.length; i++) {

                if (lv_arr[i]
                        .equalsIgnoreCase(
                                name)) {
                    position = i;

                    break;
                }

            }
```

Comment: Thank you Zain, but now they are unclickable, but when i search then click, it opens, error is: E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5

Comment: this doesn't seem to be a full stack-trace, can you debug and see if you go beyond the two conditions I put in the spinner?

Comment: E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1 E/cr_VariationsUtils: Failed reading seed file "/data/user/0/ru.tablica.sputnikovyh/app_webview/variations_seed": /data/user/0/ru.tablica.sputnikovyh/app_webview/variations_seed (No such file or directory)

Comment: `No such file or directory`.. do you try to get read/write in a directory file in your app

Comment: this sounds like an issue not related to the spinner

Comment: anyway you fixed at least half of problem, now i can open at least by search, thank you Zain!